# Image scaling, picture leaves black bars top bottom

Tags: android, image, scaling

I've got a picture 480 x 240 px in a Portrait mode.

480 wide px so it would fit on WVGA screen. However when I run the app in 240 x 320, it gets properly scaled, but leaving black bars at the top and the bottom of the picture. What can I do to solve this ?

Like this: http://t850.no-ip.org/_temp/pic01.png

Answer (score 2):

If you're using an `ImageView`, try using one of the [scaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android%3ascaleType) values. `centerCrop` is probably what you want.

Comment: No, I want the picture to be scaled as is, but I don't understand why there are the black bars. I've tried playing with scaleType, but i dont want the picture to be cropped out.

Comment: I don't get it. How do you want it to be scaled *without* the black bars?